# Django HTTP Error 404: Not Found: Using a config.json file in my views

Tags: django, django-views

I have 3 apps and one is called 'cv' but for this app I use a config.json file but it keeps giving me a 404-error when loading the page.

My project is called "project_1" and my urls.py is defined as:

```
  urlpatterns = [
  path("", include("cv.urls")),
  path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
  path("projects/", include("projects.urls")),
  path("blog/", include("blog.urls")),
]
```

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects
> and

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog

can be reached, but when I open

> http://127.0.0.1:8000

It gives me the error.

In the cv-directory, I have my urls.py defined as:

```
 urlpatterns = [
        path("", views.index, name="cv_index"),
    ]
```

And my cv/views.py as:

```
def index(request):
    BASEURL = request.build_absolute_uri()
    url = BASEURL + "/static/configuration/configuration.json"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    configuration = json.loads(response.read())
    return render(request, "index.html", configuration)
```

Where my json configuration is located in the cv directory under static>configuration>configuration.json

When I change my index function in cv/views.py to just render the request and give back my index.html file, it goes fine. So I expect it has something to do with this piece of code:

```
BASEURL = request.build_absolute_uri()
url = BASEURL + "/static/configuration/configuration.json"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
configuration = json.loads(response.read())
```

My traceback looks like this:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.9.9
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'projects',
 'blog',
 'cv']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\s.pauly\Github\portfolio\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\s.pauly\Github\portfolio\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\s.pauly\Github\portfolio\cv\views.py", line 8, in index
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Users\s.pauly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\s.pauly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\s.pauly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\s.pauly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\s.pauly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\s.pauly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

Exception Type: HTTPError at /
Exception Value: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `settings.py`, what does your static files configuration look like? More specifically, have you defined the `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` variables?

You should be accessing static assets via the `STATIC_URL`.

Additionally, I would highly advise against sending a `urllib.request` *inside a view function* to access a static asset. Instead (assuming you are using a modern version of Django), access the file in your view function like so:

```py
from django.templatetags.static import static

def index(request):
    # use the imported static function to access the file as you would in a template
    config_file = static('configuration/configuration.json')
    
    # parse the json
    config_json = json.loads(config_file)
    
    # return your template and payload
    return render(request, "index.html", configuration)
```

However, have you ran `python manage.py collecstatic`, and verified that the `configuration.json` is collected and placed in your static directory defined under the `STATIC_ROOT` variable in `settings.py`? I would suggest starting here.

Another potential issue could be your app namespacing. What does the directory structure of your `STATIC-ROOT` directory look like? I highly recommend installing the [Django Extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) plugin for development; the added `python manage.py show_urls` command is incredibly useful for debugging errors such as these.

I don't have enough rep yet to comment on other answers, but @Marco: `json.loads()` will [deserialize a valid json instance to a Python object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) (`dict`), so passing `configuration` in his render statement should be fine, assuming the json is valid. The issue right now is *accessing* the file itself-- OP's solution of sending a GET request to his /static/ path is returning a 404.

Comment: Thanks! I can fix it by explicitly putting the path string "./static/configuration/configuration.json" as my config file, but I cannot seem to get it with the static() function. I defined my static root and url respectively as "cv/static" and "static/". ps: you have to render the variable config_json in your index function, right?

Comment: @Steven01123581321 By passing a relative path string it does not matter if it is a static file or not. `static()` should give you access to all files django is able to find with it's staticfiles finder-- you likely need to tweak some static files stuff in your `settings.py`.

config_json is just what I named the variable-- it can be named anything, as long as it is a dictionary you are passing to the render function. The issue you're having is likely due to an improper configuration of `STATIC_ROOT` and/or `STATIC_URL`

What happens when you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Answer (score 0):

Django documentation for [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) says:

> render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)

So, you should pass those configuration probably as context if it's an dictionary:

```
return render(request, "index.html", context=configuration)
```

> context: A dictionary of values to add to the template context. By default, this is an empty dictionary. If a value in the dictionary is callable, the view will call it just before rendering the template.